# Random variables and marked point processes

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a probability space. Suppose that $f:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a given function (that can be continuous in its second entry). Is it possible to determine a Marked Point Process $(\Phi,\mathcal{H})$ represented by $(z_i,h_i)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that
\begin{equation}
\left\| f(\omega,\cdot)- \sum_{\Phi} h_i\chi_{[z_i,z_{i+1}](\cdot)}\right\|
\end{equation}
is smaller than a given $\delta>0$, with $\|\cdot\|$ being an adequate norm and $\chi_{(a,b)}$ is the characteristic function of the interval $(a,b)$.

If someone could give me a reference or a 'final' answer, I would really appretiate.